# Extend instance method of model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to extend a specific model in my app using railtie. Adding class methods works, but neither does instance methods. I have the following code:

```
  class Railtie
    def self.insert
      return unless defined?(::ActiveRecord)
      ::MyApp::MyModel.extend(ModelMethods)
    end
  end

  module ModelMethods
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
```

Now, I'm able to call `MyModel.hello`. But what should I do if i want to add some instance methods? When I try to add them through `::MyApp::MyModel.include(InstanceMethods)` it fails with something saying calling a private methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include` is a private method and cannot have an explicit receiver. You can get around this limitation by using `send`:

```
MyModel.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
```

Comment: a second question: Is it possitble to extend named scopes (Rails 3) instead of class methods? When I try to add a `scope :myscope, lambda...` to the module, I get, of course, an undefined method error for that module. How could I do this, so that I can add named scopes to the module that get included in MyModel?

Comment: I haven't done that myself, but you might be able to use a module callback such as Module.included: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000458 to have it call the scope method when it's included in your class. Unfortunately this comment box is limited so I can't give you a great example.

Comment: Ah ok, I'll try this. Another issue i ran into is, that in the method of the module I can't access the methods from my model. If i define a method ``hello`` in the module, and I have a method ``MyModel.test`` I can't access the test method from within hello. Any advises?

Comment: Are you getting class and instance methods mixed up? Extend will add class methods, while include will add instance methods. If you have a specific question about something, I would just create a new question and someone should be able to help you.